# How do I use the AddForce function? It won't work

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, physics

I don't know why the sprite wont jump... I want to use AddForce() instead of directly changing the velocity. [image]

```
var trump;

function Start() {
// Assigns the Rigidbody to a variable
trump = GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);

// Variable Switches:

}
function FixedUpdate() {
    GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 10;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2(0, 10));
    }

}
```

Comment: `"I don't know why the Donald Trump sprite wont jump"` :D

Comment: More force! Try * 1000 and then work back until its correct.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2(0, 10));
```

try this

```
GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up *  10);
```

Hope this works

Comment: As `Vector2.up` is shorthand for `Vector2(0, 1)`, how is that any different?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2(0, 10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);`

This will launch him into the air in an instant. I believe the problem is that you're using ForceMode2D.Force (by default), which expects to be called multiple times over several ticks. For example, ForceMode2D.Force could be used to stay on when pushing an object like a car forward.

You may consider changing this function in the future to provide smoother jumping. One good method would be applying force according to a sin function period.